# running a fancybox on load ONCE with jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to run a fancybox on page load ONCE for each visitor, using cookie plugin to track. I must be running something out of order or just initializing incorrectly. If i run this code without the cookie it init's just fine.

This is my most recent code-not working:

```
$(function(){
    if ($.cookie('visited') != 'yes'){
            $.fancybox({        
    fitToView   : true,
    width       : '581px',
    height      : '402px',
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : true,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    padding     : 0,
    closeBtn: false,
    href: 'images/navigation.jpg'
    });
        jQuery.cookie('visited', 'yes', {expires: 1, path:'/'}); 
}
});
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. Are any errors thrown? Are you sure you don't have a "visited" cookie set? You might want to clear your cookies to be sure, and compare `$.cookie('visited') != 'yes'` instead of accepting any value for "visited" cookie.

Comment: hrmm not seeing any errors. This is my first time using cookies so I must be missing something. Can you check my live code and see if anything jumps out at you? js is at the bottom of the page
http://defyordie.com/testbed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your example page at http://defyordie.com/testbed/ you are loading the scripts out of order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to load jQuery before loading the jquery.cookie plugin.

Reversing the order of the scripts should be enough.

Comment: ah there it is. Always some small oversight. That fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code as below

```
if (!(!!$.cookie('visited'))){

    ....

    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {expires: 1, path:'/'}); 

}
```

Hope it is helpful for your problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! but its not working for me